# compile only selected files dynamically using makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to know if there is a way to compile dynamically using a makefile. 
Assume I have `a.cpp`, `b.cpp`, and `c.cpp` files. These are some algorithms that I want to compare their runtime. 
First, I only want to compile a and b file and then execute to see the result. 
Next, I want to compile b and c and run.

It is not just an order, a and b can be compiled or b and c, or a and c or (a, b and c) altogether.

Can I do this using the [makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)?

Comment: Yes, you can do anything using a Makefile.  Just try.

Comment: I'd like to enter a plea that you _don't_ :) It's perfectly do-able, but it makes life a misery for maintainers, unless it's handled very carefully. It's all very well if you're compiling something that will only ever be run on the same platform. But if you ever need to cross-compile, you end up trying to execute something that was built for a different platform. Just horrible. But if you really have to do it, please provide more information about exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @KevinBoone What I want to do is for comparing algorithms' compute time. Right now, I have a very simple makefile that compiles every cpp files (algorithms code). But I am considering to create a text file as a config file to specify the name of algorithms which user want to execute by comments in and out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to "compare" runtimes, so this example just prints them via the `time` command, but you could use awk and gnuplot to generate plots if you want. Each target simply specifies a shell command to run. The `%` is used to define a target based on patterns.

```
all: ab bc

%.out: %.cpp
    gcc $< -o $@

ab: a.out b.out
    time ./a.out && time ./b.out

bc: b.out c.out
    time ./b.out && time ./c.out
```

(make sure indentation is tabs)

Comment: The way I want to compare the algorithms is like for example, I have a trajectory data and I want the algorithms to compress the data and see the time each algorithm takes. First, I want to compare the a and b algorithms then next b and c.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is just a matter of dependency ordering:  it would look something like:

```
all: results_ab results_bc
     #compare results...

results_ab: a.o b.o
     # link, and run, and store results

results_bc: results_ab b.o c.o
     # link, run and store results.
```

Comment: But if I want to compile every file (a,b and c)?
It is not an order, a user will determine which file will be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

While a compiler and makefile could potentially be worked to do this, Id suggest you **do not** do this. Restructure your program.

e.g. I am guessing you have like `test_runner.cpp`, `algorithm_a.cpp` and `algorithm_b.cpp`?

e.g. make a template function taking the algorthim to test. Then use it for each of the implementations.

```
template<class T> void test_implementation() { ... do stuff with T to test it ... }

void main()
{
    test_implementation<A>();
    test_implementation<A>();
}
```

So firstly, what is so bad about making them into one program for your test? Then you can run and time the two algorithms sequentially, or you could use a command line parameter?

Alterntively, if you consider `test_runner.cpp` as being a library, then your two algorthimns to test are seperate programs, just using that library.

Also take some time to learn the makefile syntax. Once you understand the syntax solutions should be obvious, allthough still be no means something you should apply to this situation.